# Why Codeigniter's Query Builder is returning this MySQL query wrong and twice?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, query-builder

I'm getting this string (raw copy and paste)

```
SELECT `ing_names`.`name` FROM `ingredients` INNER JOIN `ing_names` ON `ingredients`.`id_name` = `ing_names`.`id` WHERE `id_type` = '1'
SELECT `ing_names`.`name` FROM `ingredients` INNER JOIN `ing_names` ON `ingredients`.`id_name` = `ing_names`.`id` WHERE `id_type` = '1'
```

From this test code (in my model)

```
    $this->db->select('ing_names.name','ingredients.stock');
    $this->db->from('ingredients');
    $this->db->join('ing_names','ingredients.id_name = ing_names.id', 'inner');
    $this->db->where('id_type','1');

    $this->db->get();
    echo $this->db->last_query();
```

Why is query builder returning this query?

I'm trying to do this query

```
SELECT `ing_names`.`name`, `ingredients`.`stock`                    
FROM `ingredients`                                                     
INNER JOIN `ing_names`                                                   
ON `ingredients`.`id_name` = `ing_names`.`id`                      
WHERE `id_type` = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First argument to [select should be a string or an array](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/3.1.6/system/database/DB_query_builder.php#L284).

```
$this->db->select('ing_names.name, ingredients.stock');
...


//$this->db->select(['ing_names.name', 'ingredients.stock']);
```

Second argument to `select` specifies whether to escape values or not.